# Pandas create row number - but not as an index

Tags: pandas

I want to create a row number series - but not override my date index.

I can do it with a loop but I think there must be an easier way?

```
_cnt = [ ]

for i in range ( len ( df ) ):
    _cnt.append ( i )

df[ 'row' ] = _cnt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way:

```
df['row'] = range(len(df))

>>> df
          0         1
0  0.444965  0.993382
1  0.001578  0.174628
2  0.663239  0.072992
3  0.664612  0.291361
4  0.486449  0.528354
>>> df['row'] = range(len(df))
>>> df
          0         1  row
0  0.444965  0.993382    0
1  0.001578  0.174628    1
2  0.663239  0.072992    2
3  0.664612  0.291361    3
4  0.486449  0.528354    4
```

Comment: Not sure what's more efficient, but `np.arange(len(df.index))` or `np.arange(df.shape[0])` would also work.